# Best way to list files in a QFileSystemModel()?

Tags: qt, pyside, qlistview, qfilesystemmodel

I'm beginning Qt/pySide programming and am trying to implement a simple QListView with QFileSystemModel as the model.  I have this working and in addition have defined a name filter on the model.  I'd like to get a list of all files in the QListView (or rather the underlying model).

The following code *appears* to do this, but is incredibly ugly and cannot possibly be the correct way.  Help!

```
model = myQListView.model()
idx = model.index(model.rootPath())
for i in range(0, model.rowCount(idx)):
    child = idx.child(i, idx.column())
    print model.fileName(child)
```

Answer (score 4):

That is the correct way of working. The whole idea of the `QAbstractItemModel` abstraction is to provide a unified API for accessing arbitrary and possibly dynamic data which happen to fit into a list, table or tree presentations. Because this API has to accomodate everything from a simple dummy list of a few strings to the contents of an address book, including the rich contact details, it is inherently complex. Depending on what you want to achieve, using a one-purpose tool might be better in your specific situation.

By the way, the `QFileSystemModel` is very dynamic in nature (the directory enumeration happens on a separate thread). You won't get meaningful data until the `directoryLoaded` signal is emited, you have to wait for it. If you are simply looking for a list of files to use in your code, using Python's native facilities might be easier.